# In Vim, is there any way to search some word in the mode when I enter `:map`?

Tags: vim

When I enter `:map<CR>` in normal mode, I can see mapped key list.
(I don't know the name of this mode...)
But I can't search some word in the key binding list.
Even if I enter `/`, Vim just says "SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit" in bottom line, and it is also the same result when entering '?', or another key.
How can I search some word in this mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
:put =execute('map')
```

there is also a cool plugin for that https://github.com/AmaiSaeta/capture.vim